# J1 visa expiry date and ds 2019 expiry

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, j1-visas

I am J1 visa scholar. My visa and DS 2019 is expiring on July 31. My return flight from Chicago to Chennai is on Aug 1 via London with a 2 hour layover. Will this be any problem in London or USA?

Comment: Return flight from and to where? What is your citizenship? Are you relying on your US visa to transit the UK? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: I am from India. The flight is from Chicago to Chennai, India with a two hour layover at London Heathrow

Comment: Are both legs of the flight on a single booking (one PNR)? Which airline? Have you checked https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa to see if you need a transit visa?

Answer (score 4):

US visas are solely for entry, and the visa's expiration date just means the last day on which you can use that visa to enter. The visa's expiration date has no bearing on your ability to stay in the US. J1 are usually admitted for "D/S" on their I-94s, which means you remain in status indefinitely as long as you have a valid DS-2019 and comply with the requirements of J1 status. You remain in J1 status for 30 days after completing your J1 program. If your program completes July 31, you remain in status until August 30, so there is no problem if you leave August 1.

(Also, the US has no exit checks, so you would not have any problems leaving even if you overstayed; it may affect the next time you come to the US.)

Comment: So there won't be any immigration check in US? And will I have any problem in London where I am staying nearly two hours?

Comment: That's correct, there'll be no exit immigration check when you leave the US - your departure will be reported to the US government by your airline. You may need a transit visa for the UK depending on your exact situation: as @Traveller says above, you should check at https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: Related question re UK transit visa https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21259/is-transit-visa-required-for-london-uk-when-travelling-from-usa-to-india-while

Comment: I have only 4 days before my travel. Can I get DATV within this time.